# ionicons inside bootstrap 4 input

Tags: html, css, input

i would like to build an input search field with bootstrap alpha 4, but instead of glyphicon icons or font awesom, i'm using ionicons, i prefer them more.

the problem is that the icon is allways under the input field, how could i get it inside of the input field.

```
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="search" class="form-control">
    <span>
        <i class="ion-ios-search-strong pulse-icons "></i>
    </span>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their u go

```
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="input-group filter-search">
      <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Filter nach Namen...">
      <span>
        <i class="ion-ios-search-strong pulse-icons"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

You dont have to set them specif on relative, inputs are most set to relative.

```
.input-group span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two ways I think would work for you.

The easy way would be to give the `<span>` tag a `position: absolute` and place it over the input field.

```css
.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

.input-group span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 160px;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-group">
  <input type="search" class="form-control">
  <span>
    <i class="ion-ios-search-strong pulse-icons">S</i>
  </span>
</div>
```